# Is it possible to update a mongodb collection (using Mongoose) in a post method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am in a situation where I need to do 2 things:

1) Create 50+ collections and fill them with documents

2) Based on the info in each document I am adding, edit an existing collection.

The main usage first was the first step which works fine. Because I was adding collections to the DB I used a post method. Now I need to update another collection and in this case a put or even a patch http method will be better suited.

What is the correct way to approach this? Currently I am using the model.findOne and mode.Update but nothing is getting updated. I am wondering if it is due to the fact that it is a post method and not a put method

Code:
After I add tokens which works I call the function

```
                      // This adding works fine
                      new tokenModel(tokenSchema).save();
                      // This function is handling the update in a different collection
                      addTraitsToGame(tokenData);
```

And the function is:

```
const addTraitsToGame = (tokenData) => {
// Game is another collection I want to update
Game.findOne({ "opensea.game.address": tokenData.asset_contract.address })
  .then(existingGame => {
    if (existingGame) {
      newArrayToReplaceExistingOne= [];
      try {
        // Not really relevant, this is how I fill a new object that will be pushed to the new array
        for (let i = 0; i < someLength; i++) {
          let tokenTrait = tokenData.traits[i];
          let gameTrait = existingGame.opensea.traits.find(trait => trait.type === tokenTrait.trait_type);
          if (gameTrait && gameTrait.form === "values") {
            gameTrait.attributes[tokenTrait['trait_type']] = tokenTrait['trait_count']
            // This is the relevant line, filling up the array with objects
            newArrayToReplaceExistingOne.push(gameTrait);
          }
        }
        // Updating here!
        Game.update(
          { "opensea.game.address": tokenData.asset_contract.address },
          {
            $set: {
              "opensea.game.traits": traitsWithCount
            }
          },
          function (err, user) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            else {
              console.log("Update should have been successful");
            }
          }
        );
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  });
```

}

Nothing is updated after that.

Comment: please post the mongoose update code

Comment: Http PUT or POST will not change the mongoose behavior. There might be issue with your model.update or model.findOne. Please put some code in question to identify problem.

Comment: Edited with relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

```
model.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body.id},{key you need to update:"updated value"},(req,res)=>{
 your code here.
}
```

Hope it could help.